# Grouping the counts of two pandas columns into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame:

| Sport | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- |
| Baseball | 20s |
| Football | 20s |
| Baseball | 30s |
| Baseball | 20s |
| Football | 20s |
| Football | 20s |
| Football | 30s |

And the goal here is to get the counts between the two columns such that it gets the counts of each column into a list of lists  in the following format: `[['baseball', '20s', 2], ['baseball', '30s', 1], ['football', '20s', 3], ['football', '30s', 1]]` where each list consists of the format **[sport, ageGroup, count where both exist in the table]**.

Thus far, I've gotten what I needed *in a way* by doing: `sport_age_count = df.groupby(["sport", "ageGroup"]).size()`.  The problem here though is that the result isn't indexable and only treats the count like a singular list.  I get the following result with the simple code I have above:

| Sport | AgeGroup |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baseball | 20s | 2 |
|  | 30s | 1 |
| Football | 20s | 3 |
|  | 30s | 1 |

The problem is, when I try to use baseball, football, 20s, or 30s, it won't let me.  I can only access the counts.  Also, besides the fact, I'd really like this to be formatted into the **bold list of lists** like above as well.  I wasn't sure if there's any alternative python tricks out there besides using extensive for loops to build this list myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, using `.agg()`:

```
print(
    df.groupby(["Sport", "AgeGroup"], as_index=False)
    .size()
    .agg(list, axis=1)
    .tolist()
)
```

Prints:

```
[['Baseball', '20s', 2], ['Baseball', '30s', 1], ['Football', '20s', 3], ['Football', '30s', 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This solved the problem for me!  From what I gathered online, agg() seemed to be my solution, just wasn't sure how to go about utilizing it.

Comment: Any clue how you'd amend this to include counts of zero?  For example, if you also had ageGroup of 40s once for baseball, but never for football - how would you enable it to grab the count of football at 40s and specify it as zero?

Comment: @bmcisme For followup questions, I'd suggest to open a new question here on SO...Put there sample input, expected output and code you have.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that a bit later.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array (makes for easier indexing) you can reset the index and use `to_numpy()` after your groupby

```
sport_age_count.reset_index().to_numpy()

array([['Baseball', '20s', 2],
       ['Baseball', '30s', 1],
       ['Football', '20s', 3],
       ['Football', '30s', 1]], dtype=object)
```

But if you want a list of lists, you can use numpy's `tolist()`

```
sport_age_count.reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()

[['Baseball', '20s', 2],
 ['Baseball', '30s', 1],
 ['Football', '20s', 3],
 ['Football', '30s', 1]]
```

Comment: When I run the following: ```sport_age_count = df.groupby(["sport", "ageGroup"]).size()  
 sport_age_count.reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()``` It unfortunately makes zero change to the output nor does it make it indexable.

Comment: You have to assign the result to a vairable to actually change anything, apologies for not making that clear

Comment: nah it's okay, still a little dumb with python.  Python's intuitive confuses me sometimes with having a C++ background :)